# Querying and Converting Documents using Named Keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm an old SQL hand, now working with an existing Mongo database.

Rather than using arrays of embedded documents, with key information being one of the fields in the array element, each embedded document is its own field, with the key as the field name.

Suppose a collection called `bank_branches`.  Rather than this:

```
{
  branch : "St. Louis",
  branch_employees : [
    { 
       name : "Mary",
       id : "M12345"
       hire_date : Date("2010-05-20")
    },
    {
       name :  "John",
       id : "J29876",
       hire_date : Date("2015-03-23")
    }
  ]
},
{
  branch : "Jefferson City",
  branch_employees : [
    { 
       name : "Lisa",
       id : "L87653"
       hire_date : Date("2016-01-07")
    }
  ]
}
```

... we have documents like this:

```
{
  branch : "St. Louis",
  branch_employees : {
     M12345 : {
        name : "Mary",
        hire_date : Date("2010-05-20")
     },
     J29876 :  {
       name :  "John",
       hire_date : Date("2015-03-23")
     }
 }
 {
   branch : "Jefferson City",
   branch_employees : {
      L87653 : {
        name : "Lisa",
        hire_date : Date("2016-01-07")
      }
   }
}
```

(This is an invented structure to show the problem.)

Is there any way, within the MongoDB Aggregate Pipeline or otherwise, to do either of the following?

1. Query the component fields of the employee embedded documents, so that I could, for example, get all branches with employees hired in 2016, *without knowing all the field names for all the embedded documents in advance*?
2. "Unwind" these objects, so that I could have an array of branch employee documents, again *without knowing all the field names for all the embedded documents in advance*?  (The MongoDB `$unwind` pipeline operation only works on arrays.)

I suspect the first might be solvable with `$where` and `javascript`,  and/or a custom javascript stored function.  (I've never worked with stored functions before.) But I suspect the second could only be addressed programmatically.

I can satisfy my use case by writing Python and doing iteration. But I'd rather write queries to find records than filter them programmatically.  (The only guaranteed bug-free code is the code you don't have to write.)

Suggestions, anyone?  Many thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could ramble on about this but you already appear at least aware of the best answer. Convert your data to arrays. The only way you "query" the documents involves essentially manipulating the document ( per document processing ) on the server to coerce these "named keys" into arrays.

There are more "modern" methods in recent releases of MongoDB that mean you don't "have to" use [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), but there is still the main caveat where this is still in the wrong form, you simply "cannot use an index" to speed the query results.

In the basic addressing of your questions:

## Query

If you want o "find documents" by your condition on the branch employees hire date, then you can use an expression with [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) as follows:

```
db.bank_branches.find(
  function() {
    return Object.keys(this.branch_employees).some(e =>
      e.hire_date => new Date("2016-01-01") && e.hire_date < new Date("2017-01-01")
    )
  }
)
```

The main reason we're using JavaScript evaluation is because you need to "traverse the keys" of the document in a way that the query DSL cannot express, and therefore needs a condition to be evaluated against each document instead of using an index.

With more recent releases since MongoDB 3.4.4 you can use [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) for much the same purpose as [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and use it as part of an expression inside a [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) aggregation pipeline stage:

```
db.bank_branches.aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$anyElementTrue": {
          "$map": {
            "input": { "$objectToArray": "$branch_employees" },
            "in": {
              "$and": [
                { "$gte": [ "$$this.hire_date", new Date("2016-01-01") ] },
                { "$lt": [ "$$this.hire_date", new Date("2017-01-01") ] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

The [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) essentially evaluates a condition and either returns via `$$KEEP` or "removes" via `$$PRUNE` the documents based on what the boolean result of the condition was. This is similar to [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) except it is a native operator rather than using interpreted JavaScript and is essentially the "whole" query condition as opposed to [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) which is technically just another query parameter and can be used with other conditions.

From MongoDB 3.6 we get [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/query/expr/) which allows this to shorten, and even be used as the same "additional parameter" syntax as what [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) does, except with native coded operators:

```
db.bank_branches.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$anyElementTrue": {
      "$map": {
        "input": { "$objectToArray": "$branch_employees" },
        "in": {
          "$and": [
            { "$gte": [ "$$this.hire_date", new Date("2016-01-01") ] },
            { "$lt": [ "$$this.hire_date", new Date("2017-01-01") ] }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

But they are all still basically horrible since all you can do is "scan the entire collection" in order to obtain a result. So the better "array" syntax is:

```
db.bank_branches.find({
  "branch_employees": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "hire_date": { "$gte": new Date("2016-01-01"), "$lte": new Date("2017-01-01") }
    }
  }
})
```

Which can of course use an index since the path to `"branch_employees.hire_date"` is consistent, and does not use a "named key" as part of the intermediate path to the desired property. This is the prime reason you want this structure

## Reshaping

In order to actually get the documents in that "array shape", then we should have been given some indication by how the queries were constructed.

So in the first option, if writing to a "new collection" is an option for you, then in modern releases you should be able to simply do the whole conversion on the server itself:

```
db.bank_branches.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "branch": 1,
    "branch_employees": {
      "$map": {
        "input": { "$objectToArray": "$branch_employees" },
        "in": {
          "$arrayToObject": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              [{ "k": "id", "v": "$$this.k" }],
              { "$objectToArray": "$$this.v" }
            ] 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$out": "new_branches" }
])
```

Or in the case where you don't have the modern operators available or simply cannot write to a new collection, then basically looping the collection and writing back the new data for the property:

```
var ops = [];

db.bank_branches.find({ "branch_employees.0": { "$exists": false } }).forEach( doc => {

  ops.push({
    "updateOne": {
      "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
      "update": {
        "$set": {
          "branch_employees": Object.keys(doc.branch_employees).map(id =>
            Object.assign({ id },doc.branch_employees[id])
          )
        }
      }
    }
  });

  if ( ops.length > 1000 ) {
    db.bank_branches.bulkWrite(ops);
    ops = [];
  }

})


if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
  db.bank_branches.bulkWrite(ops);
  ops = [];
}
```

Both essentially use the same technique of taking the value of the object's sub-keys and merging that with the underlying object as the elements of what gets returned as an "array".

---

> **N.B** Code that runs in a [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/query/where/) expression is in JavaScript and runs on the server, so it's still a "language agnostic solution" where the "JavaScript" to be evaluated there is actually submitted as a "string" in other languages.
>
> Other expressions essentially break down to BSON representation in the language of choice. Python and Ruby are near identical to JavaScript in regards to this syntax, and the same BSON conventions apply everywhere.
>
> The other routines here are given for "conversion" of data, which as a "one off" operation should always be sufficient to run in the JavaScript execution environment of the shell.
>
> So there's no "need" to use JavaScript ( with the exception of [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/query/where/) expressions ) but the examples are given here in the common format which everyone can run in the shell provided with your MongoDB installation.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question!  You provided a lot of information that I did not know, including the newer MongoDB functionality.  I wasn't aware of `$objectToArray`, for example.  (Our servers are a bit behind the times.)

Comment: Another option I discovered after posting my question, would involve using `MapReduce` to "unwind" the named keys into a more tabular format. But I very much appreciate your explanations and examples:  they look much better than anything I've come up with.  Thanks again.

Comment: @AnnL. To be clear about the answer, `mapReduce` would simply employ the same basic JavaScript technique as indeed already demonstrated in the content of the answer using `Object.keys()` to list and then iterate the sub-keys. There is also nothing in the question about "aggregation" of data, which is the purpose of `mapReduce`, and though I show the `.aggregate()` method, it's only usage is in "querying" by logical condtion, which `mapReduce` **does not do**. You use `$where` for logical expressions, and even for "output" `mapReduce` would not be suitable for rewriting a collection.

Comment: @AnnL. So it was not an omission by accident, but simply not shown here since the context of usage does not apply to the question asked. And of course the basic logic you employ ( via `Object.keys()` ) is indeed the content here. Your main "takeaway" from this should be as the initial synopsis states, *"convert your names keys data into arrays"* since it's the only way you are going to get any "efficient" query performance from it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance and assistance.  This is far more thorough than I ever hoped for, and explains the reasons why yours is a good solution as well as simply providing the solution text.  Thank you again: I appreciate it (and apologize for the delayed response.)